# PDF.js - How to jump to bookmark using url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

How can I read the pdf in the web browser then jump to the bookmark something like this:

```
http://dev.site/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=test.pdf#section5
```

I tried using **nameddest**:

```
http://dev.site/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=test.pdf#nameddest=section5
```

But still does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6393 this issue is resolved long ago. Looks like you are using really old PDF.js version.

Comment: @async5 I tried the latest one but no luck.

Comment: See crosspost https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7836 for an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.pdf#[{"num":3040,"gen":0},{"name":"Fit"}]
```

at the end where 3040 is the bookmark number.

Note: I found this out by right clicking on a bookmark of a pdf and seeing the code for the url. The url was encoded, I simply decoded it online.

Thanks